# How to get Snapshot in FirestorePagingAdapter with Firebase Ui 8

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

Before the update from

`implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:7.2.0'`

to

`implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.0'`

I got snapshot in `FirestorePagingAdapter` like this

`val snapshot = currentList!![holder.adapterPosition]`

but after the update `currentList` is not working anymore.

I didn't find any documentation about this in the official update guide.

---

Answer: I solved the issue by using `val snapshot = getItem(holder.adapterPosition)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in the [`PagingDataAdapter` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingDataAdapter) that FirebaseUI extends, you can get an item by its position by calling `getItem(position)` or [`peek(position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingDataAdapter#peek(kotlin.Int)).

Comment: I solved the issue by using
`val snapshot = getItem(holder.adapterPosition)`

Thank you very much for helping me!

I see the information is in the link about the class you posted :)

Comment: I got the info from the links I provided in my answer. I knew to look at the `PagingDataAdapter` by looking at the source of the adapter in FirebaseUI here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/5ac863c306a4227340395c1a03d3046e13a2a670/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/paging/FirestorePagingAdapter.java#L22-L24